# Merging arrays/objects in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have

```
obj1 = {
    "prop1":{
    "prop12":[
        "Process",
      "Process Decomposition"
    ]
  }
}

obj2 = {
    "prop1":{
    "prop12":[
      "Process Decomposition"
    ]
  }
}
```

Why does using `$.extend(true, obj1, obj2)` result in these:

```
resObj = {
    prop1:{
        prop12:["Process Decomposition", "Process Decomposition"]
   }
}
```

I was expecting:

```
resObj = {
    prop1:{
        prop12:["Process", "Process Decomposition"]
   }
}
```

Can someone please suggest a better way of merging/extending two arrays/objects?

Comment: `obj1` and `obj2` are objects, not arrays. What is expected result?

Comment: Not the results I get. Provide [mcve] that replicates problem

Comment: [It doesn't](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu1skmvg/).

Comment: Jquery's extend methid will merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object. That's why you got that result. If you want both of the objects in your result, you have to create an array and push those two objects into that array.

Comment: @tjvg1991 You still didn't tell us what you are expecting. Lookup what [`$.extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) does, it doesn't even make sense to use it here considering the properties keys are the same.

Comment: Are you trying to merge `prop12` arrays?

Comment: @tjvg1991 See post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are you trying to merge prop12 arrays?
>
> yes

You can create a new object, use `for..in` to iterate properties of `obj1`, `$.merge()`, `$.unique()` to merge arrays at `obj1.prop1.prop12` and `obj2.prop1.prop12` and remove duplicate entries from resulting array.

```
var res = $.unique($.merge(obj1.prop1.prop12, obj2.prop1.prop12));
```

```js
var obj1 = {
    "prop1":{
    "prop12":[
        "Process",
      "Process Decomposition"
    ]
  }
};

var obj2 = {
    "prop1":{
    "prop12":[
      "Process Decomposition"
    ]
  }
};

var res = {};

for (var prop in obj1) {
  if (!res.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof obj1[prop] === "object") {
    res[prop] = Object.assign({}, obj1[prop])
  }
};

// merge `obj1.prop1.prop12`, `obj2.prop1.prop12` arrays, 
// removing duplicates entries
var arr = $.unique($.merge(obj1.prop1.prop12, obj2.prop1.prop12));

// set `res.prop1.prop12` to `arr` array
res.prop1.prop12 = arr;

console.log("\nres:", res, "\n\nobj1:", obj1, "\n\nobj2:", obj2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks much. I modified it slightly to cater json objects with other properties and items.